# how to filter data from from a dictionary to list

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, int> d4 = (Dictionary<string,int>)Session["Barcodes"];
```

The dictionary contains barcodes. Simultaneously,

```
List<AddInventory> Getdetails = Deserialize<List<AddInventory>>(Session[hdnPullId.Value].ToString());
```

This contains a list. In this model **AddInventory**, there is a property *Barcode* and in the `dictionary`, the string contains the *Barcode*. The `List` has many redundant entries, so i just want to have those entries in my `List`, which are present in `dictionary`.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i just want to have those entries in my List, which are present in
>   dictionary.

```
Getdetails = Getdetails.Where(i => d4.ContainsKey(i.BarCode)).ToList();
```

If you want to remove redundant entries you need to tell us which you want to keep.